# Internet stops working after installing ProtonVPN

Tags: network-manager, internet

I tried to install ProtonVPN on my Ubtuntu 20.10 via official ProtonVPN documentation. After installation, I noticed ethernet icon appearing on top-right but internet was not working. I then uninstalled protonVPN but still internet is not working even WIFI is connected. There's still ethernet icon top-right. I tried using my phone's internet via USB tethering, I was able to connect tethring but internet was still not wotking.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Recommend you to seek for help from Proton official support as well

Comment: VPNs, in general, mess with IP routing. Look at `ip route show`. You should have a "`default`" route pointing to your router.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This question is pretty old but I had the exact same problem with the exact same distro so I'll answer with how I solved it after uninstalling protonvpn.
By running

```
nmcli device
```

I found out I had two extra connections that had remained there and the system was trying to route through them, so after identifying them I simply did

```
sudo nmcli connection delete pvpn-killswitch
sudo nmcli connection delete pvpn-ipv6leak-protection
```

After that rebooting solved everything.

Also, note that there is also a workaround to use protonvpn service if after the installation internet stopped working. Simply run:

```
nmcli connection show --active
```

Then,

```
nmcli connection delete [connection name]
```

In my case the code was:

```
nmcli connection delete pvpn-ipv6leak-protection
```

After that, just open protonvpn and connect normally.

Comment: solved it by just `sudo nmcli connection delete pvpn-ipv6leak-protection`

Comment: This solved my issue. I think there's a bug with protonvpn

Comment: This solved it for me too.

Comment: Me too, thanks so much.  Very scary when you can't connect to the internet.

Comment: Amazing; thank you. Protonvpn still seems to have this issue on linux even in mid-2023

Comment: Thank you! This exact problem has been annoying me for weeks, and I finally found your solution. I'm so happy :)

Answer (score 3):

I do not know for sure that my problem was related yo yours, but after installing ProtonVPN and connecting to a server, my connection was refused when connecting to any website, despite the fact that I could ping. Well, in my case, I did

```
protonvpn-cli ks --off
```

This disables the KillSwitch function. There is a related information here too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68229831/protonvpn-broke-my-machine-after-upgrade-to-linux-cli-version-3

and after this I could connect to any server and it could allow me to connect to any web place. Dunno if this is default setup that should be avoided. Never experienced this before.

Comment: You could explain that your command disables the kill switch like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68229831/protonvpn-broke-my-machine-after-upgrade-to-linux-cli-version-3) explains it. Also you could try `sudo nmcli connection delete pvpn-ipv6leak-protection` which is an answer in the same link earlier.

Answer (score 1):

The official [Protonvpn installation page](https://protonvpn.com/support/linux-ubuntu-vpn-setup/) is giving the same solution with a few extras:
Remove any leftover files:

```
rm -rf ~/.cache/protonvpn
```

And

```
rm -rf ~/.config/protonvpn
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Pop_OS!

This used to work for me:

```
nmcli connection delete ipv6leakintrf0
```

Sometimes it'll error out saying ipv6leakintrf0 doesn't exist, even though ifconfig sees it, so I perform this guy which works

```
sudo ip link delete ipv6leakintrf0
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the blokking of my internet connection as well after installing ProtonVPN. I looked up my connections with command:
nmcli device
I found
ipv6leakintrf0  dummy     connected  pvpn-ipv6leak-protection
Killed the IP6:
sudo nmcli connection delete pvpn-ipv6leak-protection
Got:
Connection 'pvpn-ipv6leak-protection' (Blabla) successfully deleted. After that everthing worked fine. I had the same problem with NordVPN before. The problem seems to stick in the IP6 connection. My Idea is that VPN doesn't work with IP6.